# How to fill a second-floor conversation pit?

Tags: floor, joists

House was built in 1961 and has a "conversation pit" on the second floor. It may have been added when the house was last sold in 1976, see photos. I'd keep it, except whoever installed it didn't commit fully and it's just too small. It's 8'8" square and about 10" deep. It's exactly the right size to be a tripping hazard, and it's right where I want to put my couch and TV.

[image: the orgy pit from above]

Underneath, it appears that they simply ended the floor joists at two beams and put in...whatever these exposed 2x6 "joists" are:

[image: what are these]
[image]

The floor of the conversation pit is just original hardwood. No additional subflooring or anything. I feel unsafe walking on it, though it's apparently held up the last 50ish years through countless wild parties, according to the neighbors.

What are my best options for filling this in and bringing it up to level with the rest of the floor? We want to install new hardwood over everything. Can I hang new 2x6s across the pit, in parallel with the fireplace, and put down new 3/4" plywood subfloor? Or should I try to utilize the beams that run underneath and hold up the true joists? I figure that the structure they built for the pit, using wooden joist hangers and 2x6s have held so far, putting in new 2x6s above that should also hold.

Or does this go beyond a DIY, requiring a contractor?

Comment: I would be ripping up some the flooring and seeing how those cut joists are held up.  Second picture shows a crack in the plaster/drywall ceiling that might mean something or just normal house setting.  Having someone look at it is good.

Comment: The things that bother me are the beams. Are they concrete, how they are supported (seems nothing at ends to hold them up), and is there a metal deck? If they are properly supported, I wouldn't worry too much about putting new flooring in this area.

Comment: The solution depends whether you want to keep all that extra (and dare I say, ugly) timber in the room below?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an effort was made to render the below timbers stylish.

Comment: Can you pry off the riser from the step down to see what's under there? It sounds like you're not interested in salvaging any significant quantity of the material that's here, so even cutting it up would work. You'll need to know if they headered off the joists when they installed this... abomination, or if they just left them hanging and closed them up with a piece of trim. You'll need to know how much room there is below the floor to be able to slide new joists in to place.